# What arguments are passed into a CALL instruction?

Tags: disassembly, assembly

While reverse enginnering a simple C program for training, I asked myself what was the point of those lines :

```
                         LAB_001006b5                                    XREF[1]:     0010069d(j)  
    001006b5 48 8b 45 e0     MOV        RAX,qword ptr [RBP + local_28]
    001006b9 48 83 c0 08     ADD        RAX,0x8
    001006bd 48 8b 00        MOV        RAX,qword ptr [RAX]
    001006c0 48 89 c7        MOV        argc,RAX
    001006c3 e8 98 fe        CALL       <EXTERNAL>::atoi                                 int atoi(char * __nptr)
             ff ff
```

I thought that the function atoi called from the CALL instruction just pop the param from the stack (so lines from 001006b5 to 001006c0 were pointless ?)
Am I getting it right or not?

Last question : what "MOV argc,RAX" means ?? I mean, argc is a constant ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argc is an argument to the function main()

main is normally prototyped as

`int __cdecl main (int argc , char *argv[] )` when locale is not used

argc is the number of arguments passed to main  if you pass 5 arguments like
`foo.exe 1 2 3 4 5`

then argc will be 6 ( 5 arguments (space delimited ) + 1 program )

argv is a buffer that holds those arguments

```
argv[0]="foo.exe",argv[1]="1",argv[2]="2",argv[3]="3",argv[4]="4",argv[5]="5"
```

each of these arguments are 8 byte long in a 64 bit program (size of pointer)

mov [rbp+1c] , argc --> saves the numebr of arguments
cmp [rbp+1c] , 3 --> checks if you passed 2 arguments (default progname + 2 args)
if the jz jumps it reaches xxxxx6b5  to load the start of argv buffer

skips the first member argv[0] by adding 8
dereferences the second member argv[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) via mov rax , [rax]

the next mov argc , rax is a misrepresentation by ghidra

(you may need to split args and rename it )

it is not argc it is rdi the default first argument that is passed by register in [System V AMD64 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

you may check it by unlabelling or redefining the function prototype in Ghidra or

disassembling [48 89 c7 in an external disassembler like shell storm](http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/?opcodes=48%2089%20c7&arch=x86-64&endianness=little&dis_with_addr=True&dis_with_raw=True&dis_with_ins=True#disassembly)

the atoi() takes one parameter a char * and returns an integer

Answer (score 1):

1. `MOV   RAX,qword ptr [RBP + local_28]`
    
   The address of the array `argv` (i.e., the pointer to the `argv[0]` element) is loaded into the RAX register.
2. `ADD   RAX,0x8`
    
   The value in RAX register is incremented by 8 (= length of `int` in bytes), so now  in RAX is the pointer to the `argv[1]` element.
3. `MOV   RAX,qword ptr [RAX]`
    
   Now, into the RAX register is loaded the quadruple-word (i.e., 8 bytes) from the address in RAX, i.e., the *value* of the `argv[1]` element.
4. `MOV   argc,RAX`
    
   The value in RAX, i.e., the value of `argv[1]`, is loaded into the `argc` variable.

The `argc` means “arguments count”, i.e., *number of arguments*.

In this particular case, in `argv[0]` is the only argument for the `atoi()` function, and `argv[1]` is not the (non-existing) second argument – it is in fact `argc` (1 in this case) immediately following `argv[0]`.